# Dap-mode with doom emacs?

Tags: debugging, emacs

I recently switched from Vscode which has an incredible debugging experience that I’m used to.

For example, I can start an app locally, place breakpoints and run a curl request and vscode automatically puts you into the debug console where you can interpret your code

I want this workflow in emacs because Im loving everything else that emacs has to offer. However, I have to switch to vscode to actually get work done and have a good debugging experience

My current emacs configuration:

- pipenv-activate works
- projectile works
- lsp enabled
- pyright working and i get autocomplete etc
- restclient
- pytest works

But enabling the built-in debugger in .doom.d/init.el gets me nothing. Trying to M-x toggle breakpoint does nothing and gives me an error in the mini buffer

I’ve tried to configure dap-mode using a few different examples online but none work for me. Does anyone have a similar setup and know how to configure dap-mode with the default doom emacs config structure? Or do you suggest something other than dap mode?

Comment: Dunno about Doom. But you can insert breakpoints anywhere in source code by putting `(debug)` wherever you want them. `C-h f debug` tells you how to have the breakpoint also evaluate some sexp and show its value when the debugger is entered.

Answer (score 6):

**You can check helping web pages:**
https://docs.doomemacs.org/latest/modules/tools/debugger/
https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/

**In init.el, add :**
**In: tools :**
debugger +lsp)

**For example for me in C++, I need to do :

In the config.el, add:**
;; to debug with DAP-MODE
(setq dap-auto-configure-mode t)
(requires 'dap-cpptools)

Next :
M-x -> “dap-cpptools-setup” (once)
M-x -> “dap-debug-edit-template” (indicate the binary path)
Template is open, I need to complete to specify the binary
M-x -> “eval-buffer” (to be done on the template buffer to use it)
M-x -> “dap-debug” (launches the debug)